# Disarranged Pixels in XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, display-resolution

When I install an ubuntu based linux distro (specifically xfce), The operating system is not letting me choose the correct resolution of my screen.
When I choose my original screen resolution in Display Settings. It is turning my screen into this:

[image]

Comment: Originally My screen resolution is 1366X766. But Now I can only set my screen resolution to 1280X720

Comment: That is a video *kernel module* issue (ie. *driver*), but you've provided no specifics as to what Xubuntu you're asking about, and if a LTS release, if you've installed a GA or HWE stack (selected by the media used to install; of which you gave no details).  Please provide OS & release details (full details, 18.04? 18.04.1? 18.04.2? etc  whilst the stack can be changed post-install; if you tell us what media you installed with we'll know what you're using & can provide suggestions)

Comment: I am actually using Linux Mint. But It also happens when I install xubuntu. The version is 20.04 for Xubuntu and 20.1 for Linux Mint. It happens to both. But when I use any desktop environment other than xfce it is not happening

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Mint so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: I am actually using xubuntu now I can show you now. Please help me.